# Android Studio causes Binding problem in layout resource file after updating to latest version

Tags: java, android, layout, binding, resources

My Android Project was perfectly building and running. After updating Android Studio to v3.5.2 and also to latest gradle build version the build is failing without having done any changes to the code.
The problem seems to be related to Binding. The following error pops up:

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
C:\App\MyApp\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\com\project\databinding\LayoutBinding.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
import com.project.ViewModel;
                   ^
  symbol:   class ViewModel
  location: package com.hometech
C:\App\MyApp\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\com\project\databinding\LayoutBinding.java:19: error: package ViewModel does not exist
  protected ViewModel.My_ViewModel mViewModel;
                     ^
C:\App\MyApp\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\com\project\databinding\LayoutBinding.java:25: error: package ViewModel does not exist
  public abstract void setViewModel(@Nullable ViewModel.My_ViewModel ViewModel);
                                                       ^
C:\App\MyApp\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug\out\com\project\databinding\LayoutBinding.java:28: error: package ViewModel does not exist
  public ViewModel.My_ViewModel getViewModel() {
```

The related XML layout resource file that causes the problem looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="ViewModel"
            type="com.project.ViewModel.My_ViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</layout>
```

The entire build runs successful if the layout resource file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</layout>
```

But as soon as I add the `<variable ... />` part the build fails with the mentioned error messages.

(The 'ViewModel' package and the related ViewModel of course exists!)

I am super desperate about this. All the Android Binding stuff has often problems especially after updating but this time I simply do not find and fix and I tried a lot!
I appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. 
One of the error messages sais "package ViewModel does not exist".
Well, the package definitly exists and its also possible to access it from within classes.
As mentioned in my post I was able to build exactly the same project before updating Android Studio and gradle build to version 3.5.2.
I changed the naming of the package "ViewModel" to "viewmodel" and the build is finally successful again.
Also the expression "Viewmodel" was working, but only twice, the third time I tried to build the project like that failed again. A really strange behaviour of Android Studio!
So obviously something was changed in the newest Android Studio version that prevents using such a wording!
By the way, all other packages are also in camelcase like it was for "ViewModel" and they are not causing any trouble.